# Can we multiple test scenarios in single test case in testlink or any of the test management tool

Tags: testlink

So the issue is suppose am writing test cases for "Name field" in which i have positive scenarios like Uppercase, Lowercase, Uppercase+Lowercase, length, etc and negative scenarios like special characters, alphanumerics, etc .

So can i make

```
Single test case as "Positive Testcases" and include all Uppercase, Lowercase, Uppercase+Lowercase, length, etc scenarios in this.
And another single test case "Negative Testcases" and include all special characters, alphanumerics, etc in this.
```

Because, there will be n number of forms varying from country to country and language to language...

so it consumes lot of time in inputting each individual testcase, and the number of testcases will also increase.

If anyone have other solutions for the same, please provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are looking for a data-driven testing supported test case management tool.Currently, Testlink does not support data-driven testing. 
As a workaround maybe you can use custom fields to keep test data.

Some test case management systems do support data-driven testing. Ex. Microsoft Test Manager
So search for data driven testing supported test case management system, that will help you to achieve your requirement.